# moving ping-pong rackets at the same time

Tags: c++, sdl

Well, I've already started a graphic project on c++ and now I need some help.
This is a ping-pong game which has 2 rackets; one goes up and down via UP and DOWN keys, and the other moves by S and W keys.

I need to do something that it both players will be able to move their rackets at the same time.

sorry for my bad English!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include <SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1200, 800 ,32, 0);

        int i=0,j = 0;
        bool a = 0 ;
         while(true)
        {
        boxRGBA(screen, 1000, 200+j, 1050, 350+j, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        boxRGBA(screen, 100, 200+i,150,350+i,0,0,0,255);
        SDL_Event event;
                if(!SDL_PollEvent(&event));
                {
                        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                                return 0;
                        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)

                       {

                                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP)
                                    j -=10;
                                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN)
                                    j +=10;
                                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w)
                                    i-=10;
                                if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s)
                                    i+=10;
                        }
                        else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
                        a=1;
                }

            //if(a)
                //j += b;

 boxRGBA(screen, 1000, 200+j, 1050, 350+j, 255, 50, 0, 255);
 boxRGBA(screen, 100, 200+i,150,350+i,50,0,255,255);
        SDL_Flip(screen);
        SDL_Delay(2);
    }

   SDL_Delay(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really want to move the rackets 500 times a second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SDL_GetKeyboardState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) givs you a snapshot of the current state of the keyboard.

```
const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
    j -=10;
if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
    j +=10;
if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
    i -=10;
if (state[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
    i +=10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(!SDL_PollEvent(&event)); // what's ; doing here? Why are you negating the return value?
```

Try and change this to `while`:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) { ... }
```

That way it will poll all available events in the queue.

Comment: How come? What does it actually do when you press both players' controls?

Comment: they both disappear!!

Comment: But if you play with only one paddle, it does not happen?

Comment: no they both disappear !! I don't know where the problem is!!

Comment: actually I compiled it on Ubuntu